# Autostart on boot up Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I was wondering if there was a way to start up a program when I boot up my computer. Is there a folder I put it in or do I have to make a batch file. I'm really not sure.

Example: run Mozilla Firefox when I log in onto my account on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch executables and other files (batch, etc) by putting files or shortcuts in the Startup folder or in the Run registry keys.

Startup folder locations:

```
Per user - C:\Users\(User-Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
All users - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Registry Key locations:

```
Per user - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
All users - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a startup folder. Any shortcut placed in there will run when you login. Orb -> All Programs -> Startup

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the Start Menu -> All Programs -> Startup, if you want the program to startup for all users just right click the Startup folder and select 'Open all users'

If you want to prevent a program from opening at startup remove it from there or run 'msconfig' command and delete it from Startup tab.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the startup folder, in the event that you are starting multiple applications which must be started in order or when one must be ensured that another has completely started first, there are programs such as the freely downloadable [startup delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startdelay) which offer you more control over the process.